# collapse a wrappedarray elements into different columns

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe and here is the schema:

```
|-- eid: long (nullable = true)
|-- age: long (nullable = true)
|-- sex: long (nullable = true)
|-- father: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

and a sample of rows:.

```
df.select(df['father']).show()
+--------------------+
|              father|
+--------------------+
|[WrappedArray(-17...|
|[WrappedArray(-11...|
|[WrappedArray(13,...|
+--------------------+
```

and the type is

```
DataFrame[father: array<array<bigint>>]
```

What I want is collapsing the `father` column says for example if `13` is a member of this array, create a new column and return `1`, otherwise return `0`
Here is the first thing I tried:

```
def modify_values(r):
    if 13 in r:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

my_udf = udf(modify_values, IntegerType())
df.withColumn("new_col",my_udf(df['father'].getItem(0))).show()
```

and it return this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o817.showString.
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

and then I tried this one:

```
df.withColumn("new_col", F.when(1 in df["father"].getItem(0), 1).otherwise(0))
```

and the complain is:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `schema` of your `dataframe`, simple combination of `when` and `array_contains` functions should solve your issue

```
df.withColumn("new_col", when(array_contains($"father"(0), 13), 1).otherwise(0)).show(false)
```

If you want to still try with `udf` function which would be slower approach than above way, you should change your `udf` function as below

```
def my_udf = udf((array: mutable.WrappedArray[Int]) => array match{
  case x if(x.contains(13)) => 1
  case _ => 0
})

df.withColumn("new_col", my_udf($"father"(0))).show(false)
```

I hope this answer solves all of your issues